# Telegram bot can't send the same message to the group

Tags: python, telegram

I've made a script to sent some information taken from NASA API to a group in Telegram. I made a bot and I can send message but only once. I can't send the same message again. In the code I made temporary variable `k` where if I change a string it'll be sent. My main message bot has sent just once and now it's not sending it. 
Anyone's suggestion?

```
import json
import requests
import requests_cache
import schedule

from mars_api import NASA_API_KEY as nasa_key
from mars_api import BOT_TOKEN as bot_token
from mars_api import bot_chatID

# from mars_api import TELEGRAM_API_KEY as telegram_key

requests_cache.install_cache('mars_cache')


class MarsDataLoader:

    def __init__(self,nasa_key):

        self.nasa_key = nasa_key
        data_from_nasa_api = requests.get(f'https://api.nasa.gov/insight_weather/?api_key={nasa_key}&feedtype=json&ver=1.0')
        content = data_from_nasa_api.json()
        self.content = content 

class DayAtMars(MarsDataLoader):

    def __init__(self, content):
        self.today = content['sol_keys'][0]
        self.temperature_on_mars = content[self.today]['AT']['av']
        self.speed_of_wind_on_mars = content[self.today]['HWS']['av']
        self.pressure_on_mars = content[self.today]['PRE']['av']

    def create_weather_on_mars_information(self,):
        massage =f'''Goood morning! Today is going to be sunny day on Elysium Platinia. There will be no clouds. 
        Temperature outside: {self.temperature_on_mars}, light wind with {self.speed_of_wind_on_mars} m/s. Air pressure is {self.pressure_on_mars} Pa. 
        Unfortunately there is still no chance to survive outside on Mars. So brace yourself 
        and prepare for another beautifull day on Earth. In case you ARE on Mars... so sunny 
        weather but still you are in a deep shit if you are outside without a spacesuit on.'''
        return massage

k = 'harrrrry'

def telegram_send_text_massage(massage, bot_token, bot_chatID):

    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + massage

    response = requests.get(send_text)

    return response.json()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_from_nasa_api = MarsDataLoader(nasa_key)
    day_at_mars = DayAtMars(data_from_nasa_api.content)
    current_condition_on_mars = day_at_mars.create_weather_on_mars_information()
    print(type(current_condition_on_mars))
    print(type(k))
    telegram_send_text_massage(k,bot_token,bot_chatID)
    telegram_send_text_massage(current_condition_on_mars,bot_token,bot_chatID)
```

https://github.com/bartoszkobylinski/mars_weather_notification

Comment: This forum is for specific questions, or for asking for a direction to solve a problem. We are not a coding/bug-fixing service.

Comment: and about direction i'm asking. My code is working and probably is some settings in telegram bot but i can't find it. I added code just to avoid answer like: first show your code

Comment: that may be some restriction from telegram side, whats the time delay between each message ?

Comment: it's says 20 massage per minutes. But the case is that when i.e.  i have send message "make my day" and in 15 minutes i want to try again it's not appear on group but when i'm sending "mak my day" it's sending at once

Comment: there is no make my day in your code my dude... try to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), the problem will likely solve itself

Comment: current_condition_on_mars is a variable returning a massage. I have checked type and it's string (there is even a print statement print(type(current_condition_on_mars)) but i could send this massage just one time. After that massage hasn't appear on the group. So i try just insert global variable named k with a simple string here is a ''harrrrry'' and when i try one more time it has appeared in the chat. I try once again. No appearance. So i try remove/add a letter from variable k and it has show on the group. But when i try one more time... no appearance. So change to make my day and the same

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem. Since I used library requests_cache i think that was storing response there. I have remove it and now it's working! Anyway thanks for answers

Comment: Welcome to SO . please click on "Green thick" on your answer to choose as best question.